# URL schemes: application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:, handleOpenURL not called

Tags: ios, url-scheme

I am trying to launch the application from the link sent in Email.

Application gets launched from the email but `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` or `handleOpenURL` methods don't get called.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate):

`- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString*)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation`: **Asks the delegate to open a resource identified by URL**

--> so, this one gets called when you open *another* app from your app, not when your app is opened by another app

`- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`: **Tells the delegate that the launch process is almost done and the app is almost ready to run.**

--> if you already launched your app before, and it is currently only in the background, this method will not be called again

What you want is most likely:

`- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application` or `- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application` which are getting called when the app moves from the background to the foreground!